# Configuring Microservices with springboot and AWS need help to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices

I am a beginner in creating micro-services using springboot with aws. What is the best way to start?

Answer (score 0):

To start with microservices in spring boot, you can go through the [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial.
This should help you get started with Rest services.
Later you can cover topics related to data modules.

Once you get hold of the concept of how app are developed and how they execute you can go to aws and pick up a ec2 to setup the container (like tomcat) and deploy you app on it. They are multiple ways you can deploy your app on it.

You can then explore [Elastic beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) or [multi containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html)( similar to docker)

You can read [this](https://www.infoq.com/articles/boot-microservices) as well

There are just too many things to cover here. Microservices are collection of many services and you will need to provide many helper modules to help you deploy and manage these services.